# PHP - convert incorrect umlauts (utf8)

Tags: php, utf-8, iso-8859-1, iconv

how can I convert incorrect Umlauts like:

```
 ä <- Ã¤
 Ä <- Ã„
 ö <- Ã¶
 Ö <- Ã–
 ü <- Ã¼
 Ü <- Ãœ
 ß <- ÃŸ
…
```

Thats my current Code but it is not working:

```
echo iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8" "Ãœ");
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It outputs: äÄöÖüÜß

```
<?php

$inputs = [ 'Ã¤', 'Ã„', 'Ã¶', 'Ã–', 'Ã¼', 'Ãœ', 'ÃŸ' ];

foreach ($inputs as $input)
{
    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1252//TRANSLIT', $input);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mojibake is due to multiple mis-encodings between UTF8 and cp1252, which is Windows' awful version of 8859-1. If you apply the same mis-encoding in reverse you can un-corrupt your data in most cases if you're lucky.

```
$in = 'Ãœ'; // this is copied from StackOverflow where it is UTF8 encoded which 
            // may or may not match the actual encoding you pasted in.
$p1 = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $in);
$p2 = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $p1);

var_dump(
    $in, bin2hex($in),
    $p1, bin2hex($p1),
    $p2, bin2hex($p2)
);
```

Output:

```
string(4) "Ãœ"
string(8) "c383c593"
string(2) "Ü"
string(4) "c39c"
string(1) "�"
string(2) "dc"
```

And if you look up the [cp1252 encoding table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Character_set) you'll see that 0xDC is `Ü`.

But honestly you should:

1. Fix this broken data at the source.
2. [Just standardize on UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) if you can.

One or both of these will make your life easier.

**Edit:** Switched out `mb_` for `iconv` for consistency with the question. The `mb_` equivalent is:

```
$in = 'Ãœ';
$p1 = mb_convert_encoding($in, 'cp1252', 'utf-8');
$p2 = mb_convert_encoding($p1, 'cp1252', 'utf-8');
```